# Dynamically create array in C taking in 1 character at a time

Tags: c, memory-management

I am given an assignment to take in and store a string using a function, however, I am given some restrictions.

- Only able to use getchar() to take in user input character by character
- No assumption of length of the input (Not allowed to create a array of size 100 for example)
- Not allowed to read the input twice, for example, using the first round of input to count string size and then ask the user to input again after creating an array of the string's size that was counted on the first round.
- Not allowed to create a large buffer so a constant size buffer means memory will be wasted if the input is 1 character for example

  ```
  int read_string()
  {
      char* input;
      int counter = 0;

  while (( input = getchar()) != '\n')   //read until detect '\n'
  {
      printf("%c\n",input);
      counter = counter + 1;
  }
  printf("Length of string: %d\n", counter);

  }
  ```

I currently have no idea how to store character by character and dynamically resize an "array" like vectors equivalent in C++. C does not have vectors based on my research.

Based on my code now, when i type in `"Hello"`,
the output will be

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

but I do not know how to store each character in a dynamic array

Comment: I did, but there is no examples available that fits my situation directly per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use the [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) function, if you want to dynamically increase the size with every new character that you read.

When you use `realloc`, the content of the memory block is preserved up to the lesser of the new and old sizes, even if the block is moved to a new location. If the function fails to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.

For every character that I read, I increment `buffsize`, but I do allocate `buffsize + 1`. Why? Because I need one extra position for the NULL terminator.
The last free position for a letter would be `buffsize - 1` in this case and the last one will be assigned at the end of the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t buffsize = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *temp;
    char input;

    while ((input = getchar()) != '\n') {
        printf("%c\n", input);

        /* Incraese the size & realloc */
        ++buffsize;
        temp = realloc(buffer, (buffsize + 1) * sizeof(char));

        if (!temp) {
            printf("Error reallocating buffer!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Setting the new read char */
        buffer = temp;
        buffer[buffsize - 1] = input;
    }

    if (buffsize) {
        buffer[buffsize] = '\0';
        printf("Result = [%s]\n", buffer);
    } else {
        printf("Empty input!\n");
    }

    printf("String size=%lu\n", buffsize);

    /* Clean */
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, totally understand it now.! I was thinking along the lines of doubling the size of the array every time(like how C++ vectors does it)... maybe that is more inefficient?

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1

Comment: @P__J__ I know. I put it there for didactic purposes only.

Comment: @P__J__ It would be much more appreciated to list the mistakes so I can correct them and not make them in the future.

Comment: @AdrianPop you answer - and you have one very elementary UB. The program can fail instantly

Comment: And you have another error - which will lead to the memory leak if allocation failed.

Comment: @deviljones if the buffer size is doubled you would have to resize it afterwards to comply with the "no memory wastage" condition.

Comment: @P__J__ I updated my answer and I added an initial allocation in case the input is an empty string.

Comment: @AdrianPop what is this initial allocation for? Do you know how the `realloc` works? After many edits not too good. Still redundant function call and potential memory leak. You should rework your answer.

Comment: `buffer = realloc(buffer, (buffsize + 1) * sizeof(char));` reconsider it

Answer (score 1):

A bit more generic - function which adds a char to the string. Initially pointer should be NULL and it will take it into account automatically

```
char *addchar(char **str, int c)
{
    size_t len= 0;
    char *tmp;

    if(*str)
    {
        len = strlen(*str);
    }
    tmp = realloc(*str, len + 2);
    if(tmp)
    {
        *str = tmp;
        tmp[len] = c;
        tmp[len + 1] = 0;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

and usage - a bit different than yours

```
int main()
{
    char *mystring = NULL;
    int input;

    while (( input = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(input == '\n' || input == '\r') continue;
        if(!addchar(&mystring, input))
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("String length %zu\n", strlen(mystring));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, the function `getchar()` returns and `int` not `char *` so you should not assign its return value to the pointer `input` declared in your code as `char* input;`

You should start by declaring an `int` variable; could be called `len` ; and initialize it with the value of `0`. Next you should call the function `malloc()` and feed it `1` to allocate  `1` byte of memory to hold a single character, and assign its return value to the pointer `input`, like the following:

```
int len = 0;
input = malloc(1);
```

Then you should store the NUL-terminating character '\0' in the allocated memory:

```
input[0] = '\0';
```

Then you create an `int` variable since the return value of `getchar()` is `int`. This variable which could be called `ch` shall store the user input.

Then you increase the size of your allocated storage to accommodate the new character:

```
input = realloc(input, len + 1);
input[len] = ch;
len++;
```

The entire code should look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int len = 0;
    char *input = malloc(1);
    input[0] = '\0';

    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        input = realloc(input, len + 1);
        input[len] = ch;
        len++;
    }
    input[len] = '\0';

    printf("You entered: %s\n", input);
    printf("Length of str: %d\n", len);

    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @deviljones I edited the answer. Before, it had few mistakes, but now it is totally correct if you like to go over it again.